# compare ratio $x/y$ in a simple function $f(x,y)=z$

Tags: calculus

Consider the following function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+3y^2}$ where $x,y>0$

I would like to study how $f(x,y)=z$ evolves as the ratio $\displaystyle\frac{x}{y}$ increases or decreases.

Is there any classic method to tackle such questions? I having trouble with coming up with something myself...

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Rearranging gives $f(x,y) =y \sqrt{(\frac xy)^2 +3}$

And from that you can already make the observation that if $y$ remains constant, an increase in the ratio $\frac xy$ will cause an increase in the function (but you could trivially have seen that even before putting it into this form).

If you want, you can define $w=\frac xy$ and change the functional definition to $g(y,w) =y \sqrt{w^2 +3}$ allowing you to calculate partial derivatives with respect to $w$ but there's nothing you can do to remove dependence on two variables because that's the nature of a multivariate (in this case, bivariate) function.